# python the hard way ex 50: "permission denied"

Tags: python, django

Per the book, I successfully installed lpthw.web, then created the module named `app.py`. First I typed it exactly, then tried cutting and pasting from the website, to be 100% sure.

When I run `app.py` on my OS Yosemite Mac, I get the message

```
Permission denied.
```

I think it has to do with the command `import web`. I tested this by commenting out all of the lines except this one and I got the same error. However, I made a simple file, put it in bin and was able to run it. Not sure what’s going on. How do I change this?

Thanks for your help.

For reference, here is the code for bin/app.py:

```
import web 
urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())
class index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "hello world"
        return greeting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: "Permission denied" error message often mean the program is not executable, i.e., you can't run it "as is" from the shell. How are you trying to run the program? From the shel, double-clicking, through another (Python) app, ...?

Comment: Also, use the code-block formatting to format your code in the question; currently, it's just a block of characters behind each other, which is incomprehensible (we can only guess so much as to where the newlines and indentation go).

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30587467/edit) and then add the complete error message you get on your terminal.

Comment: Did you try adding executable flag to the file:  `chmod +x bin/app.py`

Comment: Please show *exactly* what you are doing to "run" this file.

Comment: To run I type > python bin/app.py. I may need to add "sudo"

Comment: I ran it with sudo, it worked!